# How to make lists of tagged data

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I have created a Google Spreadsheet of tagged data and I am trying to make different lists based on the tags. For instance, I would like to see a list of media, health and eyes records. From the data below, there should be 4 results from health, 5 results for media, and 1 result for eyes.  Note that a filter does not work for me because I would like to have 3 lists, each on separate tabs (not on the source data tab) that get updated when the source data gets updated.  So if a new record with a health tag gets added, it should show up dynamically in the health tab.

Is this even possible or do I need to create a macro?

```
Topic          |    Tag 1    |   Tag 2   |   Tag 3   |
---------------|-------------|-----------|-----------|
Natural Light  |    Health   |   Light   |   Eyes    |    
Nature Sounds  |    Health   |   Ears    |           |
Meditation     |    Health   |   Relax   |           |
Green Tea      |    Health   |   Eat     |           |
Short Stories  |    Media    |           |           |
Screen Plays   |    Media    |           |           |
Novels         |    Media    |           |           |
Documentaries  |    Media    |           |           |
Podcasts       |    Media    |           |           |
```

Comment: If you are working in a Google Sheet, then scripting is limited to the usage of Google Apps Script. Please note that not all formulae are the same between Excel and Google Sheets.

Comment: I was hoping to see if this could also be done in Excel but it's probably best to make a new question that is only related to Excel.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research I have found that the best functions for this are either "filter" or "query". In this case I have chosen to use query:

```
=QUERY($A$2:$E$13,CONCATENATE("select A where I like '%",B1, "%'"))
```

This is a really powerful way to create tagged records and report on them later.

Comment: This formula is only available in Google Sheets.